# to connect to a site having form based authentication with powershell csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, forms-authentication

i want to connect to a SharePoint 2013 site having form based authentication using powershell CSOM. With VS i can connect with X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED header. What alternative i have to use so that i can connect with powershell CSOM as well. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, normally you could add an event handler to a .NET object using the Register-ObjectEvent command.

More information is in this article:

[Accessing Mixed-Mode SharePoint Web Applications With CSOM And PowerShell](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/accessing-mixed-mode-sharepoint-web-applications-with-csom-and-powershell/)